# SCP folder that does not exist in remote

Tags: scp

How can I copy a folder and its contents (folders inside too), from my local machine to a remote machine using SCP.

I want to copy:

```
/wp-content
```

to my remote server, but wp-content does not exist there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tar the folder first and then send over scp

first tar

```
tar -zcvf wp-content.tar.gz ./wp-content
```

then send over scp

```
scp ./wp-content.tar.gz your_username@remotehost.com:/some/remote/directory
```

then login to the remote machine

```
ssh your_username@remotehost.com
```

Navigate to the directory and untar

```
cd /some/remote/directory
tar -xzvf wp-content.tar.gz ./
```

Answer (score 0):

rsync -ave ssh /wp-conent user@server_ip:/path/some_non_existing_dir_to_copy/

Answer (score 0):

```
scp -r wp-content user@remotehost:/destination
```

scp -r (recursive copy) will create the destination folder if it's not there already.